# Creating graph/chart in android which support react-native

Tags: android, react-native, gantt-chart

For my project I need gantt chart which support both android and ios. I want to start it with Android (java), but I dont know the way to expose it to react-native, such that I can use the graph in react-native and I don't find any related article for this.

first thing is after creating DemoChart.jar library, how can I make it available to be used with react-native (npm install DemoChart) javascript code & do I have to use C++ (android NDK) to bridge react-native and android.

Looking for a gantt chart, which has yAxis which shows a medical condition and it will have a horizontal line against it which scaling over xAxis (Dates or timePeriod), means in certain period (say a month) how often the medical condition has appeared

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 0):

If you don't absolutely need to use native code, there is a really powerful library of components called [Victory](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/) that allows you to make all kinds of charts. They also have a nice documentation [here](http://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs). This is compatible with both Android and iOS.